# C - Check if given argument is natural number

Tags: c, numbers, atoi

How should I correctly **check if given argument is a** **natural number** in C? I am a very beginner when it comes to C... I already have compared that argument to 1 and 2 by atoi(argv[1]) == 1 ..., but when I pass let's say 1.2137 as an argument, atoi cuts it to 1.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: `atoi` stands for "Ascii to Integer", meaning only whole numbers, if you want floating point numbers, you can use `atof`

Comment: Share some code with us

Comment: Or better yet, [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) for a function with some validation.

Comment: That's right, but I do not want floating point numbers, just want to check if it is not a float

Comment: [strtol()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) si a more advanced function that provides the capability to check the input.

Comment: Alternatively you can traverse `argv[1]` string making sure that all characters are digits (use `isdigit()`). Then you will discard input transalated to 0 by `atoi()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `long strtol(const char* nptr, char** endptr, int base)` from the header `stdlib.h` to check if your whole string can be converted to a number:

```
char* end;
strtol( argv[1], &end, 10 );
if( *end == '\0' ){
    printf( "String is a natural number\n" );
} else {
    printf( "String is not a natural number\n" );
}
```

Another way would be to check for characters that are not '+', '-' or digits

```
bool valid = true;
for( const char* it = argv[1]; *it; ++it ){
    if(!(( *it >= '0' && *it <= '9' ) || *it == '+' || *it == '-' )){
        valid = false;
    }
}
printf( "String is%s a natural number\n", valid ? "" : " not" );
```

Comment: Note that `strtol()` skips leading whitespace, so if the OP wants to reject strings with leading whitespace they would need to supplement `strtol()` with a test for that.

Comment: Negative integer numbers don't belong to the _natural numbers_ set, which is made up only by positive integer numbers.